# Symfony query builder and aliases

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, query-builder

In Symfony I have two entities(Question, Answer) that are related to each other. The relation between the two entities is ONE to MANY(one question can have many answers) Following Symfony documentation on relationships between two entities I am using a question_id field that was generated by Symfony in the answer entity. Using a query in my question entity repository I am trying to get a question with all it's answers, but following the documentation [Joining Related Records in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#joining-related-records) on how to join related records I can't understand how aliases work in Symfony.
Would really appreciate some help in understanding aliases. Thanks
This is what I have in my question repository class and in my controller. At the moment I am getting a single answer result instead of all the answers that are related to my question.

```
public function findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($questionId)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT a, q FROM QuizBundle:Answer a 
                 JOIN a.answers q 
                 WHERE a.id = :id'
            )->setParameter('id', $questionId);

        try {
            return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

public function showAction($answerId)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('QuizBundle:Answer')
            ->findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($answerId);

        $data = $product->getAnswer();

        return new Response($data);

        // ...
    }
```

Relation between my entities:

```
class Answer
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $question;

public function setQuestion(\QuizBundle\Entity\Question $question = null)
    {
        $this->question = $question;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return \QuizBundle\Entity\Question
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }
}


 class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $answers;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->answers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addAnswer(\QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answer)
    {
        $this->answers[] = $answer;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove answer
     *
     * @param \QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answer
     */

    public function removeAnswer(\QuizBundle\Entity\Answer $answer)
    {
        $this->answers->removeElement($answer);
    }

    /**
     * Get answers
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */

    public function getAnswers()
    {
        return $this->answers;
    }

  }
```

Comment: I suggest you to use the method `getOneOrNullResult()` rather than `getSingleResult()` if you only want to catch the exception for returning `null`.

Comment: can you post the relevant code that show the doctrine's relation between question and answer? probably you don't need complex DQL but you could simply navigate the relations.... (As example simply lookup for the answer then do  `$answer->getQuestions()`) let me know

Comment: @Matteo check the edited post. In my code at the moment I get just a single answer, but there are two answers for my question. The question id is referenced in the Answer entity on the field question_id.

Comment: What do you think about: 1) If you have a question object you can do: `$question->getAnswers()` 2) If you have an answer and want to get all the answers of the related question you can do: `$answer->getQuestion()->getAnswers()`

Comment: @Matteo If i am gettin the question repository and in the controller I have this code `$data = $question->getAnswers();` and I dump the data, I get a persistent collection. In the collection I do have '#collection: ArrayCollection {#462 ▼
    -elements: array:2 [▼
      0 => Answer {#455 ▶}
      1 => Answer {#453 ▶}
    ]
  }'

Comment: Hi @Otonel is this what you want?

Comment: @Matteo I want that all answers should be displayed on the screen. In the above comment I am just doing a dump, because otherwise I get $data is an object and the response must be a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116300/discussion-between-otonel-and-matteo).

Answer (score 1):

Your question refers more to Doctrine than Symfony. You should get a look at the Doctrine's documentation related to [Association Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).

There are multiple forms of OneToMany relationships. What you probably want here is to have a [bidirectional OneToMany relation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) between `Question` and `Answer`. That way, you can make a request like :

```
SELECT q, a FROM QuizBundle:Question q JOIN q.answers a WHERE q.id = :id
```

Comment: I have edited my post so you can see what I have in the controller where I am calling the function from the entity repository. Also you can see my entities. At the moment using your select statement from the comment I get my question not all my answers for the question.
I am just following this example from Symfony: [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-related-objects]

Comment: You should definitely post the code rather than a screenshot and remove meaningless sections.

Comment: With the edited code in my post I get just a single answer result, for question 1, but in my database I have two answers that relate to this question.